# Structure of "x is likely to cause deaths, both proportionally and in absolute numbers"

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, infinitives, modifiers

This sentence is an official example from *GMAT sentence correction*:

> *x* is likely to cause deaths, both proportionally and in absolute numbers.

Which part is "both proportionally and in absolute numbers" modifying? Naturally, it should be "to cause," but here "to cause" is an infinitive (as a noun) modified by adjective-likely. How come an adverb to modify a noun?

Comment: You've made two wrong assumptions: "To cause deaths" is not acting as a noun. It's an infinitival clause, not modified by "likely", but functioning as complement of "likely". The phrase "both proportionally and in absolute numbers" is an adjunct in clause structure.

Comment: Are you sure you've transcribed that accurately? It's syntactically and/or semantically invalid (***proportionally...*** must attach to some associated ***comparative***, which in this exact context could be provided by inserting the word ***more*** before ***deaths***).

Comment: hi thanks, yes there is a "more" , and the original sentence is  "a tornado of a given size and strength is likely to cause more deaths, both proportionately and in absolute numbers, in the southeastern region of the United States than in the northeastern"

Comment: Your original sentence is grammatically fine, and semantically too. A comparative clause is optional depending on the intended meaning.

Comment: @BillJ: I don't want to get bogged down in whether the mistranscribed version (without ***more***) is "invalid" on syntactic or semantic grounds (or both), but I'm in no doubt that it ***is*** invalid. Or perhaps I should say ***would be*** invalid, since apparently the actual original included ***more***, so it's fine.

Comment: Well, don't then. The OP asked about grammar, and received an appropriate response from me in my first comment. It's grammatically fine as submitted.

Comment: I don't know about your *first* post. But I am saying I disagree with your second posting claiming that the text ***as cited*** is "grammatically fine, and semantically too". I agree the entire *concept* of a comparative is "optional", but if the clause ***both proportionally and in absolute numbers*** is to be included at all, it ***must*** refer back to a comparative, imho. Only if that clause is discarded in its entirety can the word ***more*** be omitted. Whatever - I've said my piece and I don't want to argue it any further.